# run SIFT on every image in a folder and store descriptors

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sift, vlfeat

I'm trying to get descriptors for every image in a folder and store them. I want to be able to use them with vl_kmeans so I can cluster them and then build histograms based on the number of visual words for every image.
Here's the code i have so far, but descrs gives me back an empty matrix.

```
conf.dataDir = 'data\Samples' ;
N_WORDS = 400;

images = {} ;
filelist = dir(fullfile(conf.dataDir, '*.jpg'));
descrs = {} ;
parfor i=1:(size(filelist,1)-100)
    fname = filelist(i).name;
    images=imread(fname);
    [F, descrs{i}] = vl_dsift(single(images(i)),'Step', 10, 'Fast'); 
    descrs{i} = single(descrs{i});
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of mistakes, found them out and fixed them. Here's the code:

```
conf.dataDir = 'data\Samples' ;
N_WORDS = 400;

images = {};
filelist = dir(fullfile(conf.dataDir, '*.jpg'));
descrs = {};
parfor i=1:(size(filelist,1)-100)
    fname = filelist(i).name;
    images{i} = single(rgb2gray(imread(fname))) ;
    [f{i}, d{i}] = vl_dsift(images{i},'Step', 10, 'Fast'); 
end
```